# Wrong service URL in swagger-ui using JAX-RS and swagger-core

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, jax-rs, swagger-ui

I need to use openapi 3 wit swagger ui to document a jaxrs jersey service, using swagger-core v3.
I prefer use the full code approach without use config files. I'm going to use Wildfly to deploy service.

Here the code to generate openapi.json at following address: http://localhost:12079/suma-auth-ms/rest/openapi.json

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class AuthRestConfig extends Application {

  public AuthRestConfig(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
    super();

    System.out.println();
    OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
    Info info = new Info()
        .title("Suma Automaton OpenAPI")
        .description("This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger "
            + "at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, "
            + "you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.")
        .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
        .contact(new Contact()
            .email("emasil@email.com"));

    oas.info(info);
    SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
        .openAPI(oas)
        .prettyPrint(true)
        .resourcePackages(Stream.of("io.swagger.sample.resource").collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    try {
      new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder<>()
          .servletConfig(servletConfig)
          .application(this)
          .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
          .buildContext(true);
    } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

  }
}
```

and here you can see openapi.json file at mentioned address:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "paths": {
        "/rest/authentication/authenticateUser": {
            "post": {
                "operationId": "authenticateUser",
                "requestBody": {
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Credentials"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "default": {
                        "description": "default response",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Credentials": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "username": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "password": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in this file there's no references to suma-auth-ms, service response correctly at http://localhost:12079/suma-auth-ms/rest/authentication/authenticateUser

When I'm going to take a look to the swagger ui, andr try to execute some tests, I've this result:
[image]

Error shown is due to lack of suma-auth-ms in the address used by curl to call the service. Address should be http://localhost:12079/suma-auth-ms/rest/authentication/authenticateUser and not http://localhost:12079/rest/authentication/authenticateUser

Is there a way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server* and add it into your oas object.

```
oas.info(info);
String url = "/suma-auth-ms/"
List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>();
Server server = new Server();
server.setUrl(url);
servers.add(server);
oas.setServers(servers)
```

After making this change you should see *servers* listed in your openapi.json and you will be able to hit request with *suma-auth-ms* added

Comment: Thanks for reply. swagger-core seems ignore my configurations. Using previus config, adding your config or using an empty Application:
`@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class AuthRestConfig extends Application {

  public AuthRestConfig() {

  }
}`
give me same result. Any ideas?

Comment: There is one difference may be you can try.....In my case I have used a custom servlet class for Swagger configuration and created a separate class for JAX-RS configuration which is working fine.

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for that?